# Writing to txt doc on new line Java

Tags: java, file

```
public void writePlayerTurnActions(String action){
        File file = new File(this.playerFileName);

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.playerFileName);

            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            writer.write(action + "\n");
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to player output file");
        }
    }
```

Here is the method im using to keep updating a file depending on what occurs during the execution of the program. Im calling it by

```
instance.writePlayerTurnActions("1");
instance.writePlayerTurnActions("2");
instance.writePlayerTurnActions("3");
```

When running this code the file only contains a 3... and not 1, 2, 3 on seperate lines.

Any help appreciated as i'm so confused as to whats going wrong...

Comment: You are not appending, you are overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

you should not create a new `FileWriter` instance each time you want to write something (not only because of this issue, it's also very bad performance wise). Instead, keep one globally and instead of calling `writer.close()` when you're done writing your current String to the file, call `writer.flush()`.